# How many Fairy Tail members went missing from the guild during the timeskip?

Tags: fairy-tail

**Contains spoilers for fans who have not reached the timeskip.**

The story takes a seven year timeskip at the end of the Tenrou Island arc. Members who went to the Tenrou Island to participate in the S-rank exam go missing. With the 8 exam participants and their respective partners, the 3 examiners, Master Makarov, and Laxus, that would be **21** members. Is this calculation correct?

Answer (score 11):

At the end of the Tenrou Island arc,

> Acnologia sinks the Tenrou Island along with all the people on it.

- Mest Gryder, one of the eight exam participants, is actually a Magic Council member, and he left the island earlier anyway.
- Gray's partner, Loke/Leo, returned to the spirit world earlier.
- Wendy and Gajeel took their Exceed partners, Carla and Pantherlily respectively, to the Tenrou Island.
- Laxus was not a member at this time, since he had been expelled and Makarov refused to readmit him.

Taking all the above into account, altogether **20** Fairy Tail members (and Laxus) were missing from the guild during the timeskip.

List of members (clockwise in the human circle they formed, starting from Lucy and excluding Laxus):

1. Lucy Heartfilia
2. Natsu Dragneel
3. Erza Scarlet
4. Cana Alberona
5. Gildarts Clive
6. Levy McGarden
7. Gajeel Redfox
8. Wendy Marvel
9. Carla
10. Happy
11. Pantherlily
12. Makarov
13. Bickslow
14. Freed Justine
15. Evergreen
16. Elfman Strauss
17. Mirajane Strauss
18. Lisanna Strauss
19. Juvia Lockser
20. Gray Fullbuster

[image: Fairy Tail human circle]

Comment: actually wendy and gajeel didn't take carla and panterlily to tenroujima, they came on their own accord because carla had a premonition about a terrible event on tenroujima